# How to get contour of foreground on a white background using OpenCV?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, opencv, contour, image-segmentation

**Goal:**

I am training a tensorflow model to be able to outline what a jacket/shirt is. In order to create this model, I must create a dataset of masks from pictures of shirts. unfortunately, I was unable to find any datasets that did this for me or any pre existing models that could handle this task.

Because of this, I am trying to use OpenCV to create my own dataset. The problem is, I can't get consistent results with different images.

Here is the code that I grabbed from the OpenCV website on making contours:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import cv2

im = cv2.imread('./jackets/jacket.jpg')
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray,127,255,0)
im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Create an output of all zeroes that has the same shape as the input
# image
out = np.zeros_like(im)

# On this output, draw all of the contours that we have detected
# in white, and set the thickness to be 3 pixels
cv2.drawContours(out, contours, 1, 255, cv2.FILLED)

# Spawn new windows that shows us the donut
# (in grayscale) and the detected contour
cv2.imshow('Original', im) 
cv2.imshow('Generated Mask', out)

# Wait indefinitely until you push a key.  Once you do, close the windows
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This code works great for some pictures, giving me exactly what I want. Here is an example of OpenCV doing what I want:

[image: OpenCV when is contours successfully]

Unfortunately, it does not work for all my images. Here are a few examples where it fails spectacularly.

Example 1:

[image: Fail #1]

Example 2:

[image]

Anyone have any suggestion on fixing this?

Comment: Floodfill from the edges.

Comment: Instead of fixed threshold , try something like OSTU threshold which should work well here

Comment: It's better to have some original samples

Comment: @alkasm BTW you were right. If you post the comment as an answer (with maybe a little code for others), I'll accept you as an answer :)

Comment: @Gabe appreciate the ping! I have a previous answer that does something similar, so I'll flag as a dupe.

Comment: @alkasm Done! Up-voted your answer there as well. Thank you for taking the time to answer the question!

Comment: @Gabe Can you please post your code which worked?